# How to add with jQuery two or more rows with same ID on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a list of products fetched from API and bellow table is a button. I'm trying to achieve appending another table only with tr elements from the first table that have "product-row" ID.
I'm using find() method and it works but I can't add it all at once, so I must click the button for each row. But when I put as parameter "tr" in find method it works. So my question is how to append another table with all rows with specific ID at once.

```
$("#tableBody").on("click", "#addToAspect", function(){
    // #addToAspect is ID of button
    var row = $("#tableBody").find("#product-row"); // this is ID of row
   $("#aspectTable").append(row); // #aspectTable is second table

})
```

Comment: You can't because ids are supposed to be unique in dom. So, jquery will always return the first matched element with that id. You can either use `tr` or `class` attribute instead.

Comment: Just as @palaѕн wrote, you should use classes to match multiple elements and then loop through them and add them to another table. Be careful also you with appending elements that are already in dom, because that will usually just move them (unless that's what you actually want). So clone them before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one **unique ID** on page - this is **mandatory**.

`var row = $("#tableBody").find("#product-row");` - will always return only first found element with ID = product-row.

Can you replace #product-row with class .product-row?
If you can't do anything with your code - I suggest use it in this way:

```
$("#tableBody tr").each(function(index, elem){
    if(elem.attr('ID') === 'product-row'){
        $("#aspectTable").append(elem);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, It works now  I've changed  with class .product-row